# Magento 2 Mass shipment

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, shipment, massaction

I have found mass Invoice in the following link,

[How to create invoices for more than one order via mass action?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80710/how-to-create-invoices-for-more-than-one-order-via-mass-action)

Similarly, how to create shipment for more than one order via mass action drop down ?

Comment: Hi, Will it support Magento 2.1.7 version? Because I am getting the following error. a:4:{i:0;s:172:"Invalid XML in file demo/app/code/Ship/ordermass/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml:
Premature end of data in tag config line 2
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="admin">
    <route id="ordermass" frontName="ordermass">
        <module name="Ship_ordermass" />
    </route>
</router>

Comment: Hi, Its fixed now, I have changed the routeid and frontName as ship_ordermass. Its working as expected. Thank you Hasham.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Made the ui component in your module

> app\code\Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <action name="order_ship">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">order_ship_mass</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Ship</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="ordermass/order/massShip"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Ship</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to create shipment for selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            </massaction>
</listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

Then added route file in your module

> app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\adminhtml\routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="admin">
    <route id="ordermass" frontName="ordermass">
        <module name="Vendor_Module" />
    </route>
</router>
```

After that add Mass Ship Adminhtml Controller in your module

> app\code\Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\MassShip.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;

class MassShip extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AbstractMassAction
{

    protected $orderManagement;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Filter $filter,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession

    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $filter);
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->orderManagement = $orderManagement;
    }

    protected function massAction(AbstractCollection $collection)
    {
        $countShipOrder = 0; $NonShipOrdernuumbers = '';
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order');

        $username = $this->authSession->getUser()->getUsername();
        $appendusername = "(".$username.")";

        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $order) {
            if (!$order->getEntityId()) {
                continue;
            }
            $loadedOrder = $model->load($order->getEntityId());

            if($loadedOrder->canShip()) {


            $convertOrder = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order');
            $shipment = $convertOrder->toShipment($loadedOrder);

            // Loop through order items
            foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {
                // Check if order item has qty to ship or is virtual
                if (! $orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
                    continue;
                }
                $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
                // Create shipment item with qty
                $shipmentItem = $convertOrder->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);
                // Add shipment item to shipment
                $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
            }

            // Register shipment
            $shipment->register();
            $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

            try {
                // Save created shipment and order
                $shipment->save();
                $shipment->getOrder()->save();
                //send notification code
                $loadedOrder->addStatusHistoryComment(
                __('Notified customer about shipment #%1. '.$appendusername, $shipment->getId())
                )->setIsCustomerNotified(false)->save();

                $itemsCheck = $loadedOrder->getItemsCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
                foreach ($itemsCheck as $item) {
                    if (! $item->getQtyToShip() || $item->getIsVirtual()) { 
                    continue;
                    }
                    $item->setQtyShipped($item->getQtyToShip());
                    $item->save();
                    $Norder = $shipment->getOrder()->load( $shipment->getOrder()->getId() );
                    $Norder->save();
                }

                // Send email
                $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier')
                    ->notify($shipment);

                $shipment->save();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
            }

            if ($loadedOrder->canInvoice()) {
            $loadedOrder->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
            $loadedOrder->setStatus('shipped');
            $loadedOrder->addStatusToHistory('shipped', 'Order status set to shipped using Mass Ship action. '.$appendusername);
            $loadedOrder->save();
            }

            $countShipOrder++;
            }
            else {
                if (empty($NonShipOrdernuumbers)){
                $NonShipOrdernuumbers = $NonShipOrdernuumbers.$loadedOrder->getIncrementId();
                }
                else{
                $NonShipOrdernuumbers = $NonShipOrdernuumbers.", ".$loadedOrder->getIncrementId();  
                }
            }
        }
        $countNonShipOrder = $collection->count() - $countShipOrder;

        if ($countNonShipOrder && $countShipOrder) {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('%1 order(s) Shipment created successfully.', $countShipOrder));
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Shipment already created for %1 order(s).', $NonShipOrdernuumbers));
        } elseif ($countNonShipOrder) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Shipment already created for %1 order(s).', $NonShipOrdernuumbers));
        }

        if ($countShipOrder) {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('%1 order(s) Shipment created successfully.', $countShipOrder));
        }

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath($this->getComponentRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

I wrote this code, I already tested this code. If you still find any difficulty then please tell me on comment section